# Como habilitar um button após validação?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Preciso que o `button` seja habilitado quando o email não existir no banco de dados. Veja que a validação se o email existir já funciona, preciso da implementação que habilite o botão caso o email não exista.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#email').blur(function() {
        $th = $(this);
          $.ajax({
            url: 'plano.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {email: $th.val()},
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#resultados").html("Carregando...");
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#resultados").html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#resultados").html("Ouve um erro ao enviar sua URL");
            }
         });//ajax       
    });
});

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="resultados"></div>
<button id="registrar" disabled="disabled" type="submit">CONTRATAR AGORA!</button>
```

**plano.php**

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
    #Conecta banco de dados 
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM conta WHERE email = '$email' ORDER BY EMAIL ASC LIMIT 1");

    while($sqlregistro=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $emailbanco = $sqlregistro['email'];
}

    echo $emailbanco;
    echo "<br>";

    if(isset($email ) && $emailbanco === $email ){
        echo "Este email existe no banco";
    }else{
        echo "Email digitado " .$emailbanco. " Nao existe no banco "; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...

success: function(data){
    $("#resultados").html(data);
    if(data.search("Nao existe") != -1)
        $("#registrar" ).prop( "disabled", false );
},

...
```

Comment: Funcionou em parte, deixa eu explicar o que aconteceu. Quando eu digito um email que existe realmente o código mantém desabilitado o botão. E quando eu insiro um email que não existe ele habilita o botão. Perfeito!!!
Porém, quando eu digito um email que não existe e em seguida eu redigito outro que existe ele não desabilita, e mantém habilitado. O correto seria que a cada vez que eu sair do campo ´email´ ele habilitasse ou desabilitasse o botão.

Comment: Faz assim... No blur, antes da linha `$th = $(this);`, coloque `$("#registrar" ).prop( "disabled", true );`. Ou então faça um `$('#email').keyup(()=>{$("#registrar" ).prop( "disabled", true );})` que aí sempre vai desabilitar e só vai habilitar quando rolar o success no Ajax. :)

Comment: Infelizmente não deu

Comment: Botou pra desabilitar no keyup?

Comment: sim, coloquei. mas não funcionou.

Comment: Como fazer para se existir o email ele apaga o que estiver no input do email?

Comment: O keyup tá fora do blur, né? Estranho...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81435/discussion-between-gladison-and-thxmxx).